vgg16 issue after 1 epoch it shows the error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items
here is the link:https://www.kaggle.com/code/psamsahil/alzheimer-prediction-using-tl-1/edit
i m working alzymer oasis data set used imagedatagenerator for data argumentation al information is in link
just can you tell how to resolve the issue

The notebook you've linked showed a KeyError, which is different than the error you're describing. Which of the two is the issue?
